# System seems to freeze when using chrome and google docs

Tags: google-chrome

i’m a newbie, since i installed EOS just six days ago and i’m not and expert. 
To me Elementary is definitely fine, it suits all my needs, but i m faced with the following PROBLEM: the system randomly freezes when using google chrome and its office extensions- like google docs.
I don’t know, maybe i’m wrong and its just the touchpad that stops working...but it happens even when i m using a wireless mouse, and by the way the issue occours only while using chrome...

any suggestions to solve the problem?

I have an Acer Swift 1 SF113-31-P6YM - Pentium 1.1 GHz - 13.3" - 4 GB RAM 
I have done all the updates; and as you may expect , i installed chrome through the Terminal.

Thank you!
Daniel

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054738/ubuntu-18-04-freezes-while-im-using-chrome)?

Answer (score 1):

Try to put chrome icon on the dock, and other applications you work with.

Comment: Your participation is much appreciated Let me inform you that we love informative answers with step by step guide. Have a nice day!